# Prove that $\tan x =\sin x + 1$ have only one solution in $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: calculus

Prove that $\tan x = \sin x + 1$ have only one solution in $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

Well, I believe I need to show that there's a solution. so I need to find x which solves $\tan x = \sin x + 1$.

Then, I need to derivate it and show that the derivation either bigger than zero, or smaller than zero, Thus - there will be no solutions.

So in intuition way, I know how to solve it, but practically I'm having difficulties. Can you guys help with the steps I've shown?

I believe It's Rolle's rule. Because we just studied it :)

Comment: So you know you need to differentiate $\tan x - (\sin x  + 1)$. What do you get when you do so?

Comment: @HenningMakholm x = 0

Comment: @HenningMakholm Because $cos^3x = 1$ Thus, x = 0.

Comment: x @Ilan: Um, that doesn't even look like a derivative. Please explain how you conclude that "$x=0$" (which is an equation, not a function) is the derivative of $\tan x - (\sin x+1)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well, $sec^2x -cosx = 0$ ,

Comment: x @Ilan: Where do you get that equation from? Why do you think you need to solve that equation in order to find the derivative of $\tan x - (\sin x + 1)$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I derivate tanx, and I derivate sinx, and I derivate 1.

Comment: x @Ilan: That does not answer my question: **Why do you think you need to solve that equation in order to find the derivative of $\tan x - (\sin x + 1)$?** As far as I can tell, solving that equation tells you **absolutely nothing** you nee to know here, and as long as you keep refusing to reveal **why** you start solving that equation, you can have no serious expectation of getting any help.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Because if I solve it, I know that I have one solution.

Comment: x @Ilan: Why do you care whether there are solutions to $\sec^2 x - \cos x =0$, when the problem you're solving asks about solutions to the _completely different equation_ $\tan x = \sin x + 1$?

Comment: I care if I have ONE solution to $tanx - sinx - 1 = 0$ if I have ONE solution, I need to derivate $tanx - sinx - 1 = 0$ and see if the derivation is bigger or smaller than zero.

Comment: x @Ilan: What you need to see is that the derivative is $\ge 0$ everywhere (and is not $0$ in any open interval). Finding the point where the derivative is zero is not going to help you with that -- especially not if you forget _what the derivative is_ and only report the results of your labors as $x=0$. That's throwing the baby out with the bathwater and then complaining that the rubber ducky you have left is not any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the formulas
$$
\tan x=\frac{2t}{1-t^2},\qquad
\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}
$$
where $t=\tan(x/2)$. Then the equation becomes
$$
\frac{2t}{1-t^2}=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}+1
$$
that can be rewritten
$$
2t+2t^3=2t-2t^3+1-t^4
$$
and finally
$$
t^4+4t^3-1=0
$$
We want only solutions in the range $-1<t<1$, because we want $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$, so $-\pi/4<x/2<\pi/4$.

Set $f(t)=t^4+4t^3-1$; since $f(-1)=-4$ and $f(1)=4$, we know that one solution exists.

Consider $f'(t)=4t^3+12t^2=4t^2(t+3)$. This is positive for $t\in[-1,1]$, except at $0$; therefore the function is strictly increasing in the given interval, hence we have only one solution.

---

You can also consider
$$
f(x)=\tan x-\sin x-1
$$
and note that
$$
\lim_{x\to-\pi/2^+}f(x)=-\infty,
\qquad
\lim_{x\to\pi/2^-}f(x)=\infty
$$
which implies a solution exists. Then
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}-\cos x=\frac{1-\cos^3x}{\cos^2x}
$$
which only vanishes at $0$ and is positive elsewhere, in the given domain $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Thus $f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: I like the second explanation. Thank you @egreg !

Answer (score 1):

let me rewrite the equation as $$\tan t = \sin t + 1.\tag 1$$  i will use $x = \cos t, y = \sin t.$ then $(1)$ becomes $$\frac y x = y + 1 \to y = \frac x{1-x}\tag 2 $$

the solution to $(1)$ are the points where the hyperbola (2) cuts the unit circle in the first quadrant. this is easy to see because the  branch of the hyperbola going through $(0,0)$ can only cut the unit circle at one in the first quadrant and the second time at a pint in the third quadrant.

Answer (score -1):

$\tan(x)$ is a bijection from $]-\pi/2, \pi/2[$ to $]-\infty, \infty[$ as a continous and increasing function (derivative >0). $\sin(x)+1$ is increasing, continuous function: this is a bijection from $]-\pi/2, \pi/2[$ to $]0,2[$.

hence, the two graphs must have a unique common point as $\sin(x)+1 \in [0, 2|$. To have an interval, you apply the Bolzano's theorem:

if f is continuous on [a,b] and f(a)< 0 and f(b)>0 then, there is $\alpha$ where $f(\alpha)=0$. $\alpha$ is unique if f is a bijection on [a,b] (example : f monotone).

here $f(x)=\tan(x)-\sin(x)-1$. we have $\alpha=1.08264952...$

Comment: There can be more than one point of intersection between two continuous strictly increasing functions: Just consider $x = \sin(x)+x$ on $[-100,100]$.

Comment: these functions are bijectives from $]-\infty, \infty[$ to $]-\infty, \infty[$ which is not the case here where one of the functions is borned.

Comment: @Claudeh5 If you consider Henning's example on interval $[-100\pi,100\pi]$ then both $x$ and $\sin x+x$ are strictly increasing bijections from $[-100\pi,100\pi]$ to itself, yet the functions have many points in common.

Comment: You compare two different cases. You have two increasing bijections from ]a,b[ to ]f(a), f(b)[ (f(a) is finished and f(b) finished also ) and idem for g with a case where one function is increasing and bijective from ]a,b[ to $\mathbb{R}$ and the other is increasing  BUT BORNED.

Comment: What does "borned" mean? Do you mean "bounded"?

Comment: If you want a real counterexample, you have $f(x)=tan(x)+1$ and $g(x)=1/(1+5x^2)$

Comment: Ah yes, bounded ! (borné in french = bounded). The  previous examples  from Makholm and Wojowu are not in the case (unbounded, bounded).